# How to reference existing data in table with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm creating a api with Java, Spring Boot and Hibernate. The objective is save guests in a list.

Everything is working normally, but when I enter guests with the same group, in the database it creates a new row, and gets repeated information.

There is the class Guest

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "con_convidado")
public class Convidado {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Length(max = 20)
    private String name;


    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Grupo group;


    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Age ageRange;

    public Convidado() {

    }
```

And the class Group

```java
@Entity
public class Grupo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String nome;
```

I wish that when I inserted a new guest with an existing group, a new group with the same name would not be created.

Comment: Please show how you save the entity

Comment: Don't understand, how i save where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You group is using id as primary key. If you want your new guest to be created in the existing group you need to set its id.

Something like that

```
var group = findGroupByName(name);
if (group == null) group = new Group(name);
guest2.setGroup(group);
```

Or you can just make group.name your PK by removing id and marking name with @Id annotation.